# Issues with Firebase Auth.$requireAuth()

Tags: angularjs, firebase

So I was reading up on Firebase's "User Authentication" section to find a way to stop un-authenticated users from accessing specific pages (i.e. when they're not logged in)

The solution I came across, was to use this snipet of code:

```
resolve: {
      // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
      // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
      'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth) {
        // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
        // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
        return Auth.$requireAuth();
      }]
    }
```

So after I put that in and tried to access the specific page without being logged in, I got the following error message in the console:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- currentAuth
```

If I try to log in after words, I am unable to navigate to that specific page.

I've been searching around for a few hours to find a solution to this and most people said it was a dependency issue with not having "ngRoute" included in my app.js file. However I do have that dependency included so I know that's not the issue.

```
angular
  .module('App', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.sortable',
    'firebase',
    'angular-toArrayFilter'
  ])
  .constant('fb', {
    url: 'https://<url>.firebaseio.com/'
  })
  .factory('fireBaseRef', function(fb) {
    return new Firebase(fb.url);
  })
  .factory('UserAuth', function($firebaseAuth, fireBaseRef){
    return $firebaseAuth(fireBaseRef);
  })
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'login_controller'
      })
      .when('/view_resources', {
        templateUrl: 'views/view_resources.html',
        controller: 'ViewResourcesCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'view_resources',
        resolve: {
          // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
          // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
          'currentAuth': ['Auth', function(Auth) {
            // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
            // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
            return Auth.$requireAuth();
          }]
        }
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried to declare $routerProvider like this: `.config( [$routerProvider , function($routeProvider) {...}]);` ?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what difference would that make? I tried to set it up like that just to see if anything change and I just got an error saying $routeProvider is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think your factory

```
.factory('UserAuth', function($firebaseAuth, fireBaseRef){
    return $firebaseAuth(fireBaseRef);
  })
```

should be named as "Auth" as follow:

```
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth, fireBaseRef){
    return $firebaseAuth(fireBaseRef);
  })
```