# Angular route login $requireAuth()

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

I have a problem with my `Auth.$requiredAuth()`

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider.state('cursustext', {
  url: '/cursustext',
  templateUrl: 'views/cursustext/cursustext.html',
  controller: 'cursustextCtrl',
  resolved: {
   "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth){
     return Auth.$requireAuth();
   }]
  }
 })
})
```

-

```
.factory('Auth', function($firebaseAuth){
 var auth = $firebaseAuth();
 return auth;
})
```

Problem is: When I'm not logged in, I can still go to the page.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Sincerely,
Jur

***EDIT/UPDATE***

```js
angular.module('myApp.cursustext', ['ui.router'])

.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $state.go('home');
    }
  });
}])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('cursustext', {
    url: '/cursustext',
    templateUrl: 'views/cursustext/cursustext.html',
    controller: 'cursustextCtrl',
    resolve: {
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        return Auth.$requireSignIn();
      }]
    }
  })
```

It works now. But when i'm not logged in, isn't redirect to home page. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo here:

```
resolved: {
   "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth){
     return Auth.$requireAuth();
   }]
}
```

should be resolve

```
resolve: { 
   "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth){
     return Auth.$requireAuth();
   }]
}
```

A resolve contains one or more dependency that must resolve successfully before the route will change, most likely this prevent the parser to force the resolution of the Auth dependency and that's why you can see the state without be logged.

**EDIT**:
to handle the case of error you can do this:

```
resolve: { 
   "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth){
      return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(resp){
        return resp;
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        $location.path('/home'); //redirect to home page in case of error
      })
    }]
}
```

Comment: i have change it, but now i got a error: `stateService.ts:525 Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: TypeError: Auth.$requireAuth is not a function)`

Comment: ok now the resolve block is reached, try to see if this topic can help you . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042270/issues-with-firebase-auth-requireauth

Comment: It works now. But when i'm not logged in, isn't redirect to home page. how? {see code above}

Answer (score 1):

hey hope you fixed the issue, anyway i ran into the same problem

```
stateService.ts:525 Transition Rejection
```

I solved this by using older version of Angular Ui Router.

```
bower install angular-ui-router#0.3.1
```

The Latest Ui router had issues with Angularfire Auth example.
Cheers

Comment: I was looking for this for hours, thank you!. Is there any other workaround that doesnt imply downgrading ui-router?